# Random crashes in Monotouch app

Tags: crash, xamarin.ios

I'm getting random crashes in my Monotouch iOS app. The crashes occur after some time using the application. They also often occur after locking and unlocking the device. There are two stacktraces that appear in this crashes, this:

```
0 ogaza 0x00003382 + 0
1 ogaza 0x00003fac + 0
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x327e17ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x327d720e pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x327d029e abort + 94
5 ogaza 0x00684666 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6626814
6 ogaza 0x005dc0ee _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5937286
7 ogaza 0x005dc3b6 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5937998
8 ogaza 0x006501a0 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6412600
9 ogaza 0x00650f16 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6416046
10 ogaza 0x00650fd8 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6416240
11 ogaza 0x005e8244 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5986780
12 ogaza 0x005e83f0 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5987208
13 ogaza 0x005e70c2 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5982298
14 ogaza 0x002ffd87 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 2938143
15 ogaza 0x004579eb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4346243
16 ogaza 0x00457d0b _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4347043
17 ogaza 0x00458e73 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4351499
18 ogaza 0x00457c17 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4346799
19 ogaza 0x004577bb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4345683
20 ogaza 0x00415ed3 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4077163
21 ogaza 0x00415abf _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4076119
22 ogaza 0x004807db _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4513651
23 ogaza 0x004801eb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4512131
24 ogaza 0x0046db27 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4436671
25 ogaza 0x003fdc7b _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 3978259
26 ogaza 0x003ffacb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 3986019
27 ogaza 0x0004d2a3 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 109115
28 ogaza 0x002aa467 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 2587647
29 ogaza 0x005d4172 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5904650
30 ogaza 0x0064f996 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6410542
31 ogaza 0x005bf8d6 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5820526
32 CoreFoundation 0x3532f3fc -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
33 UIKit 0x32e24e06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
34 UIKit 0x32e24dc2 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
35 UIKit 0x32e24da0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
36 UIKit 0x32e24b10 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 492
37 UIKit 0x32e25448 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 476
38 UIKit 0x32e17b86 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5222
39 CoreFoundation 0x353a9b1a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
40 CoreFoundation 0x353a7d56 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 258
41 CoreFoundation 0x353a80b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
42 CoreFoundation 0x3532b4a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
43 CoreFoundation 0x3532b36c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
44 GraphicsServices 0x36fc7438 GSEventRunModal + 136
45 UIKit 0x32e37cd4 UIApplicationMain + 1080
46 ogaza 0x000712b3 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 256587
47 ogaza 0x003d7777 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 3821327
48 ogaza 0x002aa467 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 2587647
49 ogaza 0x005d4172 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5904650
50 ogaza 0x0064f996 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6410542
51 ogaza 0x006526ae _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6422086
52 ogaza 0x00655fda _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6436722
53 ogaza 0x005d8bce _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5923686
54 ogaza 0x00695697 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6696495
55 ogaza 0x00032bfb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 915
```

And this:

```
0 ogaza 0x00003382 + 0
1 ogaza 0x00003fac + 0
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x327e17ec _sigtramp + 48
3 ogaza 0x00053b8f _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 135975
4 ogaza 0x0047abff _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4490135
5 ogaza 0x00406cdb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 4015219
6 ogaza 0x002aa467 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 2587647
7 ogaza 0x005d4172 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5904650
8 ogaza 0x0064f996 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6410542
9 ogaza 0x005cc522 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5872826
10 UIKit 0x32e4bb94 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 144
11 UIKit 0x32ea5d84 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 264
12 UIKit 0x32e68250 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 680
13 UIKit 0x32e67fa0 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 292
14 UIKit 0x32e67cba -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 650
15 UIKit 0x32e67a2e -[UINavigationTransitionView _navigationTransitionDidStop] + 62
16 UIKit 0x32e1eaaa -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 470
17 UIKit 0x32e243d4 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 52
18 QuartzCore 0x3222ac2e _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 202
19 libdispatch.dylib 0x34264ee6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 194
20 CoreFoundation 0x353a82ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
21 CoreFoundation 0x3532b4a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
22 CoreFoundation 0x3532b36c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23 GraphicsServices 0x36fc7438 GSEventRunModal + 136
24 UIKit 0x32e37cd4 UIApplicationMain + 1080
25 ogaza 0x000712b3 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 256587
26 ogaza 0x003d7777 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 3821327
27 ogaza 0x002aa467 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 2587647
28 ogaza 0x005d4172 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5904650
29 ogaza 0x0064f996 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6410542
30 ogaza 0x006526ae _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6422086
31 ogaza 0x00655fda _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6436722
32 ogaza 0x005d8bce _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 5923686
33 ogaza 0x00695697 _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 6696495
34 ogaza 0x00032bfb _ZNSt6vectorIhSaIhEEC2IPKhEET_S5_RKS0_ + 915
```

I suspect there are some problems with memory management. I tried several tips from around the internet like:

- When using classes inherited from UITableViewCell save them in an array in my viewcontroller.
- Save all controls where I attach events in class fields.
- Use SGen GC with reference counting extension

None of this worked.

Any hint on what I could do to debug this?

Comment: Can you create the crash while debugging on the device?  That should give you better information.

Answer (score 1):

1.Try debug on device, here is [how to](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started/debugging)

2.Try Add try catch on entry point

```
public class Application
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

3.Try subscribe on UnhandledException

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
        .....
    }

    private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e.ExceptionObject);
    }
```

4.Take a look on [Monotouch limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations)

Comment: Thanks GSerko. I had a related problem with this. I was actually handling the exceptions in Main, but writing them with Console.WriteLine, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. The root of the issue was TestFlight crash reporting which was making Monotouch debug misbehave. After removing TestFlight in debug builds I got a proper error report from Mono with this issue:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_2